# Is hash command available in all popular Linux shells?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hash, ssh

I need `hash` command to run via ssh on server but I have no guarantee which shell it uses. Is the hash command available in all popular shell and does it have the same return codes?

Comment: It is defined in [this POSIX document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/hash.html), so any POSIX-compliant shell should have it.

Comment: IMHO you could only have problems in `csh` shells that are explicitely not Posix, or on old Bourne shells. Anyway, if you have commands that depend on a particular shell, you should make sure to use that shell. *I have no guarantee which shell it uses* is weird: different environments use different shell, but always the same when called the same way...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I need to programmatically connect via ssh to multiple Linux machines. I can't assume that all of them will use the same environment and I want to run hash to check if particular commands are available on them.

Comment: I'd rather use `which` to know whether a command exists and where it lives. It may be implemented as a builtin, but at least it exists as a true command if the shell does not implement it.

Comment: Since, like @fedorqui mentioned, `hash` is a POSIX command, is it not safer to assume to be present?